# Why there is a function named bind() in this aureliaJS-reactJS example?

Tags: reactjs, bind, aurelia

Why there is a function named **bind()** in this [AureliaJS-ReactJS example](https://github.com/cscleison/AureliaReactPOC/blob/master/src/hello.js)? Is this a callback method for Aurelia or React which will be called during the application life cycle?

```
@noView()
@inject(Element)
export class Hello {

  @bindable foo = "!";

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  render() {
    ReactDom.render(<HelloTest foo={this.foo} />, this.element);
  }

  bind() {
    this.render();
  }

  fooChanged() {
    this.render();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind` is an Aurelia [view life-cycle hook](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#extending-html):

> `bind(bindingContext:any)` - Invoked when the databinding engine binds the view. The binding context is the instance that the view is databound to.

In the example because the `Hello` extension is decorated with `@noView()` (so Aurelia does not try to look-up a template for it) the `bind` hooked is used to render the React component to the bound `this.element`.